# How can we add some text before controller name in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, seo

i have a SEO requirement that when the user is logged in, their username should be displayed before the contrroller name.

I.e.

- example.com/home - currently looks like this
- example.com/username/home - I want it to look like this

i have tried some basic modification in routes.php such as:

```
Router::connect('/haresh/:controller', array('action' => 'index'));
```

with this, it works, but this option is lost the base path so all images are 
   disappear. I.e. image urls like this:

```
<img src='img/xyz.png' />
```

Don't work.

How do I modify the url so that `/username/` is prefixed to all urls, and fix the image path problem?

Comment: I've edited your question because it was hard to understand - please review it.

Answer (score 3):

### SEO applies to anonymous users

If the urls in the question only apply to users that have logged in - they are of zero SEO value - because googlebot et.al. will never login to your site, and if they did - all urls would be `/googlebots-username/...`.

### SEO Routes

Assuming that these user urls are publicly accessible (see previous point, if they aren't they are of no value), all you need to do is define a route for them:

```
// define other routes first
Router::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about'));

Router::connect('/:username/:controller', array('controller' => 'default', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:username/:controller/:action', array('controller' => 'default', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:username/:controller/:action/*', array('controller' => 'default', 'action' => 'index'));
```

You can then access the username property inside your controllers as

```
$username = $this->request->params['named']['username'];
```

### Fixing images

This is a seperate problem, but the simple fix is to use an [appropriate helper method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3aimage):

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('xyz.png', array('alt' => 'to the abc')); ?>
```

The answer to *most* markup problems is to use an appropriate helper method.

#### Alternatively

Or just use an absolute url:

```
<img src='/img/xyz.png' />
```

Obviously if the url is changing - using a relative path for assets means the image that is requested changes depending on the current url.

Answer (score 0):

if its just image path problem you can use either solution

1 use html helper class of cakephp

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->image('xyz.png', array('alt' => 'alternate text')); ?>
```

2 use webroot path

```
<img src='<?php echo $this->webroot ?>img/xyz.png' />
```